# swiper javascript is not working in website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to include the group swiper javascript in my website which can swipe group of 4 slides or product cards which is at the bottom of the site one time but it is not working properly.

Where am I going wrong?

webpage link:  [hosted webpage link](https://kiran-yadav-13.github.io/E-Commerce-webpage/)

Repo link : [repo link](https://github.com/kiran-yadav-13/E-Commerce-webpage)

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Comment: the product cards at the bottom of site are not swipping in groups (which was expected)

Comment: You haven't given swiper-slide css to bottom cards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.